# Why is RowPrePaint being called continuously?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and implemented the `RowPrePaint` event like this:

```
private void dgData_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    int multiplier = (int)dgData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["multiplier"].Value;
    bool marked = (bool)(dgData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Tag ?? false);

    if (multiplier > 1)
    {
        dgData.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xff);
    }
    if (marked)
    {
        dgData.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf2);
    }
}
```

When I have all this code, I can see my grid is being re-painted continuously (which is confirmed when adding a log statement). When I comment the code out, the re-paint is done only when needed.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why are you changing the Cell Style in `RowPrePaint` in the first place? You're essentially asking the row to repaint itself. So, it's not a surprise that the event is triggered again. You should probably handle the `CellValueChanged` event instead (since the cell value is what you're using to determine the color).

Comment: Now, in a (different) situation where you actually need to use the `RowPrePaint` event, you'd have to paint its parts yourself by altering `e.PaintParts` and custom-drawing the target parts. See [Customize the Appearance of Rows in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/customize-the-appearance-of-rows-in-the-datagrid?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for more.

Comment: @41686d6564 No idea. This is what I came up with and it worked fine (until now ;-). It works without continuous repainting in other parts of the code, and even when I use a different dataset (added an extra `WHERE` clause), this doesn't happen. Of course, I am very much open to another way of coloring rows based on the actual row data (that being the actual goal here).

Comment: You could use `CellValueChanged` as suggested above or (probably more appropriate) the `CellFormatting` event. If you go with the latter, don't alter the `DefaultCellStyle` of the cell directly; use `e.CellStyle` instead.

Comment: @41686d6564 thanks, you could make an answer for me to accept if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the Cell Style in the `RowPrePaint` event, you're effectively asking the row to repaint itself causing the said event to be triggered again. This can even repeat indefinitely if the color is changed each time as demonstrated in the following code:

```
private static Random random = new Random();
private void dgData_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    dgData.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 
        Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 256), 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xff);
}
```

For your particular situation, there are two ways I could think of to change the cell style.

1. If you need to alter the actual `DefaultCellStyle` of the row, and since the color is determined (partially) based on the cell value, you may handle the [`CellValueChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged) event. Assuming the rows' `Tag` property doesn't change, you'd be good to go. Otherwise, you'll need to execute the same code after changing the row tag.
2. If you only want to change the displayed color, you may use the [`CellFormatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting) event which exposes a `DataGridViewCellStyle` property via its EventArgs. Do not alter the `DefaultCellStyle` in that event, otherwise, you'll end up with the same problem (re-triggering the same event). Instead, you may use `e.CellStyle` for the same purpose:

   ```
   private void dgData_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
   {
       e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(...);
   }
   ```